# How to get rid of the “X now favors Y as the heir” messages

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I have started playing CK2 as a Count of Olomouc, which means I am part of the Holy Roman Empire. But probably because of that, I constantly get messages like this one in Low Priority Messages:

> Duke Heinrich VIII now favors Duke Magnus I as the heir to the Holy Roman Empire.

I want to read all the other low priority messages, but not these, they don't seem relevant to me (at least for now) and they are very frequent.

I went through the Message Settings, but didn't find any option for this. Which of the many options controls these messages? Or is there some other way to turn them off? (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Discard is not good enough for me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a loading screen message, right click on the message, which will show you a window that lets you customize this exact kind of message, without looking for the right kind of message in the long list:

[image: Options window for the “Successor Nominated” message type]

Answer (score 0):

In the headger? I dont know if thats the right word sry... ledger? That window that shows you stuff like counties revenue, armies, fleets... Theres a button there. When you click that button you get window with many boxes, marked, and unmarked. Theres a box related to the messages you receive.

Check that box and look at the ledger again.

There you will see stuff like:
Receive messages from your liege... when you click it, it turns to "receive messages from all your lieges", click again and it will turn to "receive no liege messages".

You can customize it to receive only messages rom disnaty members, direct subjetcs, other rulers, etc.

Very useful stuff!